# ACPIDriver.exe for Lenovo won't open

Tags: power-management, lenovo-laptop, windows-installer

I got a  Lenovo y50-70 and I want to install their power management application. I download the .exe from their website which doesn't do anything. The icon appears in the taskbar for half a second then closes. What can be the issue here?

Comment: try to check what's happening in the backgroung by using Sysninternals ProcMon

Comment: ok I installed and found like 7 ACPIDriver.tmp ? what now

Comment: I managed to filter them. http://i.imgur.com/E7JDntR.png what now?

Comment: you can filter by "your process name" for example, and see if there are missing resources or something else

Comment: can't see the whole text, reupload the image again

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/G3Cyf what should I do now?

Comment: Expand the Path text and check next to "Not Found" Values, maybe it's a registry issue with x64 Windows

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/rGHvL looks like they are quite a lot